# How to setup Windows to share user directory over SMB

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, smb

In SAMBA for Linux I can automatically create share for every users home directory, is this possible for Windows too?

I have Windows 10 and 11 OSes, where every new user account should has his home directory (or other subdirectory in his home) shared. Is this possible without manual sharing for every user account? Of course this sharing should work like with SAMBA, so only owner has access to it remotely.

Comment: Windows has no such automatic feature, and there is also the unclear question of what does include a user's "home directory". The concepts are vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

Share the entire `C:\Users` folder.

This is what Windows does when you use the "Sharing Wizard". One share with per-user folders is also how most SMB file servers are set up for AD "Folder Redirection (among other things, it allows a client machine automatically create the per-user folder on the server).

Users then will be able to access their files through `\\pc1\Users\mario`.

> Of course this sharing should work like with SAMBA, so only owner has access to it remotely.

It already works like Samba – or rather, *Samba works like Windows* – because file access through SMB still honors the filesystem-level ACLs that have been set on the individual files and folders.

This means you can just set the SMB-level share permission (the Windows equivalent of `write list =`) to "Everyone:Full" and let NTFS ACLs handle it – just don't confuse the two very similar-looking 'Security' tabs when doing so.

(This also applies to Samba; it honors Linux file permissions so you can also have a single [Users] share if you like.)